# Options for handling expensive queries in a stateless application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stateless

I have a DB query which takes about 30 seconds to run.  I need to use the results of that a web-application, for example populate a dropdown listbox with the results.

Obviously I don't want to run the query every time the page is loaded.  I suppose I could write the results to a temporary table, but was wondering if there are some "best practices" on how to handle expensive operations in a stateless application.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about caching. It's a big topic, and it's not easy to provide a succinct answer.

Comment: could the query be optimized?  seems like a long query for a dropdownlist